# Json Column configuration

Tags: mariadb

I am using mariadb and I will create a table with two columns and an int primary key.
This table will start with about 3.000.000 rows and will be added approximately 30.000 rows per day.
each column will have 200 to 700 characters.

There will be  some searches against these two columns either as text or json query.

I am thinking of make these column as mediumtext data type and also set full text index.
I am quite new to this and I don't know, Is that a correct approach ?

Comment: *There will be some searches against these two columns either as text or json query.* Show some data example and both searches types patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Pick either `TEXT` or Json, based on the needs.

`TEXT` (up to 64KB) or `MEDIUMTEXT` (up to 16MB) plus `FULLTEXT` indexing is useful for very efficient seraching for "words" in unstructured prose.  There are limits on what a "word" is -- in length and in avoiding "stop words" such as "the".

JSON is for structured text, usually key-value pairs, possibly arrays and associative arrays.  But the search capabilities are limited.  What specific version of MariaDB (or MySQL) do you expect to use?

To help you further, we really need some insight into the type of data and application.